# Put scaled instance in the center of each edge in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create sort of a engineering structure. I want to model an object "the traditional way" and then, in Gemoetry Nodes, put a joint in each vertex of the original model and then truss/bar along each edge.

I am trying the "truss/bar along each edge" part:

1. I was planning to add a cube instance in the middle of each edge,
2. reorient it
3. and scale to reach each end of the edge,

but I'm stuck in *1*

Original model:

[image: Original model]

What I have tried - I only got to add the instances at the ends of the edges:

[image: What I have tried]

Result:

[image: result]

Can somebody help me find my way? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if I interpreted your question correctly, but as I understood it, that's what you want to achieve here:

[image]

Here I divide the edges of the cylinder into vertical and horizontal edges.

I use the edges as a base curve to extrude a square profile from along them.

I use the vertices to instantiate at these cubes.

---

And here is another variant, which actually instantiates new cubes in the middle of the edges, and scales them according to the edge length:

[image]

*Please bear with me, and give me some feedback if this is what you wanted, then I'll be happy to explain more.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on your chosen method ..

An option would be to create an arbitrarily-placed collection of cube-instances, 1 per edge of your mesh, (they will be indexed 'in parallel' to the mesh edges..):

[image]

.. and *then* position them at the center of mesh-edges, using *Transfer Attribute*, on the Edge domain, by index..

[image]

.. which will place a cube-instance at the center of each mesh-edge. You can use similar transfers to pass over edge-length and direction, and edge-normal.

Using all those transferred attributes together, you can scale and orient your cube-instances, without having to realize them. Knuckles are instanced on vertices:

[image]

[image]