# Geometry Nodes: Instance per edge and orient/scale instances to edge length

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges, instances, vector

I am trying to have one instance per edge, and have that instance stretch from each point on the edges. I've almost got it working via Transfer Attribute, but it's not able to pull exact distances, as shown below:

[image: Transfer Attribute by Closest]

Alternatively, when using Transfer Attribute by Index it works, but still not quite: [image: Transfer Attribute by Index]

I can sense by how it's working a little bit in both scenarios that the answer is out there. What is the missing link to solve this?

Comment: You could look at the methods in answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/267904/35559)

Comment: That worked! The trick was putting it on Scale Instances, rather than the initial Scale of the instance on points